# ActionView::MissingTemplate during testing

Tags: ruby-on-rails, testing

I'm testing a rails controller and attempting to perform a get with the code:

```
delete :remove_logs, :id => 3
```

And it consistently returns me an ActionView::MissingTemplate exception. I know that this is because there is no view associated with the get. There is a route for this method (from rake routes):

```
remove_logs        /devices/remove_logs/:id(.:format)            {:controller=>"devices", :action=>"remove_logs"}
```

The function itself works perfectly for the actually webpage as it's being called with:

```
<%= link_to "Remove History", remove_logs_path(device), 
:class => "medium red button",  :confirm => 'This will remove all history from 
this device. Are you sure?', :method => :delete %>
```

So my question is, is there a way to bypass or trick the test to not attempt to access the view and just access the controller method? This isn't my system I'm testing so I really don't want to make a new blank view or anything similar.

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem may be related with the code in controller (remove_logs action) which usually has some code about redirecting to another url like bellow:

```
def destroy
  @tag = Tag.find(params[:id])
  @tag.destroy
  redirect_to :action => :index
end
```

I test with Test::Unit in my rails app, and it goes fine when having redirecting code.